# Where is the "official" annotations api?

Tags: java, annotations, expression, el

I am reading a tutorial about stripes security that tells me to annotate like this

```
@RolesAllowed({
  "Administrator",
  "User if ${user eq message.folder.user}"
})
```

But I think I want to do something else in my own case, use another operator or such. I have googled but not succeeded. Where is the "manual" for annotation expressions.

I look forward to understand the explanation for:

```
${//some expression}
```

and also that `if` and `eq` operators, where is the "list"?

Comment: the `if` and `eq` operations are EL expression: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html

Comment: `${//some expression}` is within a string - the annotation API knows nothing about what is in that string. It is the API that exposes the annotation that is going to parse the string to extract the expression. You need to find the documentation of that API.

Comment: ... and from the annotation perspective, that is just a String ( that will be parsed/processed/evaluated at runtime )

Answer (score 1):

Placeholders / expressions are not part of Java annotations. "`User if ${user eq message.folder.user}"` is just a String from Java annotation perspective. In the above case it is only the annotation processor (stripes?) who knows how to interpret `${user eq message.folder.user}` expression.